# nested if else statement wont go to if else section

Tags: java, if-statement, iterator, java.util.scanner

I am having a problem with my nested if else statement. I am inputting a item title and I am trying to make it so if that item title does not exist in my database the program will tell the user that the title does not exist. My program currently skips over the else if statement that should be outputting "no entry" any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
else if (Option == 2) {
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("item title");
                title = scan.nextLine();
                boolean found = false;
            for (MediaItem mi : media){ if (mi.getTitle().equals(title) && mi.onLoan == true){
                found = true;    
                System.out.println("already on loan");
                     break a;
            } if (!flag) {System.out.println("This title does not exist in the library");
            break a;}

             }
                System.out.println("Who are you loaning it to?");
                loanedTo = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("When did you loan it to them?");
                dateLoaned = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: just being curious, what do you expect `break a;` does?

Comment: i apologize the break a breaks out of both the loop and the nested loop and resets the program to start at the beginning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few guessing and more clarification from your side, i believe this is what you are looking for:

```
System.out.println("Item Title:");
title = scan.nextLine();
boolean found = false;
for (MediaItem mi : media){ 
    if (mi.getTitle().equals(title) && mi.onLoan == true){
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Already Loaned");
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("no entry");
}
```

Comment: I would guess this is the problem. Although if you want to make sure it's not just white space in general, you'll need to trim/strip it before testing for emptiness (I forget what the Java string operation is to do so ATM).

Comment: That is still not working. I the program does not even seem to reach the else if statement. The program is just skipping right past if the nested if else statement when the field does not exist

Comment: @YellowSoloCup, Could you tell us the exact case you want "no entry" to be output ?

Comment: I would like the program to output "no entry" when the program does not have entered title in memory. The program is an array of objects. The objects are movie title and format. So if the title is not saved in one of the objects then "no entry".

Comment: And if the title is in the Database but is already loan, you want it to print "no entry" ? and if so you want it to be printed after "Already Loan" or instead ? To tell us the exact conditions you want everything to occur is much much more important and easier than to let us guess.

Comment: I apologize, I would like the program to tell me "no entry" if the title is not in the database and tell me "already loan" if it is in the database. The "already loan" section is working fine.

Comment: @YellowSoloCup, And if it's inside the Datebase but isn't loan ? I told you, you should tell us what you need to do/print for all possible outcomes.

Comment: if it is inside of the database but isn't loan then I would like the program to continue with the initial loop. I will add the rest of the loop for option 2.

Comment: @YellowSoloCup, I believe my answer covered what you needed and you can take it from here.

Comment: The program is still giving me the same results as before and continuing with the program without checking if the title exists.

Comment: `equals()` is case sensible, if you entering a capital letter where you shouldn't it will return `false`, if that in fact the case than use `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: @YellowSoloCup, Man you did lots of mistakes at your code, and that is after you meshed it up with my code. Please rewrite your logic to a page and then attack the problem.

Comment: Ok, sounds like I have a lot of work ahead of me. Thank you very much for your time and help.